# React and Google Drive Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I created a file upload button via google drive in my project using React - javascript. I did this using npm i react-google-drive-picker. I used the code you see next:

```
import  { useEffect } from 'react';
import useDrivePicker from 'react-google-drive-picker'


function App() {
  const [openPicker, data] = useDrivePicker();
  // const customViewsArray = [new google.picker.DocsView()]; // custom view
  const handleOpenPicker = () => {
    openPicker({
    
      clientId: "*******************",
      developerKey: "*****************",
      viewId: "DOCS",
      
      
      // token: token, // pass oauth token in case you already have one
      showUploadView: true,
      showUploadFolders: true,
      supportDrives: true,
      multiselect: true,
      
      // customViews: customViewsArray, // custom view
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // do anything with the selected/uploaded files
    if(data){
      data.docs.map(i => console.log(i.name))
    }
  }, [data])


  return (
    <div>
        <button className="picker"onClick={() => handleOpenPicker()}>
        
        <p>Import from Google Drive</p>
        


        </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It works, when i clicked the import  from google drive button the account choosing menu is displaying then i choose an account but it says
The API developer key is invalid.

So, how can i import my API key in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried activate your API key?

https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview